# Converting integers to string in ANSI

Tags: c, arrays, string, integer

I know there are lots of questions about converting integers to string but I couldn't find anything mentions about the ANSI standards.

I am trying to write my program in ANSI standard so "itoa" and "sprintf" aren't helpful.

Writing them on my own is way off me as I am a beginner.

What I am exactly dealing with is an array, I want to convert only one element of the array each time and write this into a string. the array should remain so I can continue to use it. I will only send one element to the function.

What can I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "ANSI standards"?

Comment: what code.. I didn't start to write my own converting function as I just can't do it. I was hoping there might be a solution in ANSI

Comment: _"sprintf" aren't helpful._ what mean ?

Comment: ANSI C? not C89 or c99 things

Comment: `sprintf()` is part of the standard library. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY itoa and sprintf don't present in ANSI C. so I can't use them

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves really? I read something about it isn't a part of it. So ı can use it?

Comment: See the section HISTORY at [`sprintf`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sprintf+3). sprintf even precedes ANSI C.

Comment: @user3108849 The C standard library is specified in ANSI C standard. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library. `sprintf` is really old, you can use it with no worries.

Comment: Thanks! Then this would be a very stupid question right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sprintf` is indeed defined by the C standard. I would not look past that function to solve your problem.